# Jersey 2.26 and Spring 4.3.10 but no HK2

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

Is it possible to configure Jersey 2.26.x that it solely depends on Spring for injection instead of HK2? I know Jersey is nowadays compatible with Spring, but is it also possible to get completely rid of HK2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't.  Jersey uses many special features of hk2 (such as good integration with Spring and Guice) in order to function

Comment: Starting in 2.26, Jersey actually got rid of HK2 as a hard dependency. It [stole some of your classes](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject), added its own packaging, and now makes the DI provider pluggable through an InjectionManager. There's currently [CDI and HK2](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/inject) implementations.

Comment: I guess that's true for customer applications.  They still use hk2 heavily internally