# How to get HK2 ServiceLocator in a Jersey2 ServletContainer?

Tags: guice, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'd like to get Jersey2 and Guice to cooperate together, which is apparently rather difficult. I've seen some solution to this involving using the HK2-to-Guice bridge. But the bridge rely on getting the HK2 `ServiceLocator` instance in the `init()` of a custom Jersey2 `ServletContainer` in order to initialize `GuiceBrige`:

```
public class MyServletContainer extends ServletContainer {
  @Override public void init() {
    ServiceLocator sloc = getApplicationHandler().getServiceLocator();
    ...
} }
```

But somehow in the latests version of Jersey (2.26), the `getServiceLocator()` does not longer exists in `ApplicationHandler`. How can I get it in this context?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't use Guice, so this is not something that I have tested. So I don't know if what the OP is trying to do will even work. I am simply answering the main question of how to get the ServiceLocator.

---

As mentioned in [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620576/jersey-2-26-and-spring-4-3-10-but-no-hk2#comment78209510_45624308), starting 2.26, Jersey no longer has a *hard* dependency on HK2. So throughout its codebase, you will no longer see a reference to a `ServiceLocator`, but instead, a higher level `InjectionManager`. The `InjectionManager` has the same purpose as the `ServiceLocator`, but the abstraction allows for different implementations of the dependency injection provider. This is why, when using 2.26, we need to add the `jersey-hk2` dependency. This is the HK2 implementation of the `InjectionManager`. In this implementation, the `InjectionManager` will simply delegate calls to the underlying `ServiceLocator` where appropriate.

That being said, the `ApplicationHandler` gives you access to the `InjectionManager` now, rather than the `ServiceLocator`. The `ServiceLocator` itself is a service, so if you have a locator you could do the following (which is pointless, but it just shows my point)

```
ServiceLocator locator = getServiceLocator();
locator = locator.getService(ServiceLocator.class);
```

This means that you can also get the locator from the `InjectionManager`, which is just a high level delegator for the underlying locator

```
InjectionManager im = getApplicationHandler().getInjectionManager();
ServiceLocator locator = im.getInstance(ServiceLocator.class);
```

One thing that needs to be pointed out, and the main reason for my disclaimer is that you need to call `super.init()` *first* in your `init()` method, or else you will get an NPE when you try to get the `ApplicationHandler`. The problem with this is that there is *alot* of initialization done; pretty much the entire application is initialized. So it may or may not be too late to try and add your Guice integration.

Here are some other places where I have seen this integration done. And I believe they would all be hit before you trying to do it at the end of the `init()`.

- In a `ResourceConfig` constructor, where you could inject the `InjectionManager`.
- In a `Feature` where you could get the `InjectionManager` through the `InjectionManagerProvider` static method.
- I have not seen any implementation of this, but I think the preferred location to do the bridge would be in a `ComponentProvider`, as mentioned in [the docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e17202). The only implementation I have seen is for Spring. You can see the source in the [jersey-spring4](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.26/ext/spring4/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring). This is probably requires more work, but I think it would be the most appropriate location, as it is called before all the other previous options. It may not be required though, as I've seen others get away with the other two options.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Thanks for pointing out that Jersey >2.26 no longer has a hard dependency on HK2, which was the biggest drawback of migrating from Jersey 1.x to 2.x (we use Guice everywhere else, so having to make two DI to cooperate is a pain).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I ended up registering the ServiceLocator -- which I injected from my `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclass -- in a global static class and hoping that it was available at the right time. It was and it worked, but I didn't know I could have achieved the same thing by using

```
InjectionMananger#getInstance(ServiceLocator.class);
```

it's a bit tidier that way.

An alternative is to put the class name of an implementation of `ServiceLocatorGenerator` in META-INF/services. this will get you control of the root service locator for the entire application before it ever reaches Jersey. The issue here is that the single method that must be overridden must return a new `ServiceLocator` object but you can't use `ServiceLocatorFactory` to create this object since it causes infinite recursion. So you must create and configure a `ServiceLocatorImpl` which is quite involved. However, a `ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl` exists which can simply be copied from github and used as your implementation. You can bridge Guice to HK2 here before anything else happens. I haven't tried it yet but will soon.